# How to correctly enforce referential integrity in a update/insert trigger?

Tags: sql-server

Database: SQL Server, 2017.

I need to enforce certain business rules in a trigger. Now, before you tell me to use a foreign key, please know that the rules are too complicated to be enforced by foreign keys. With that out of the way, let me get to the meat of my question:

Is this the correct way to rollback/cancel the insert/update in a trigger if a business rule is violated:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTestTrigger]
   ON  [dbo].[MyTestTable]
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[MyTestTrigger]')) > 1
    BEGIN
        RETURN;
    END

    if (condition_is_true) begin
         ;throw 51000, 'Bad data Message.',1;  
    end
end
```

I know my question seems simple, but I stumbled on this "[treatise](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html)" on error handling in SQL Server. After skimming through it, I came away with the impression that error handing is extremely complicated. One thing I am confused about is, do I need to explicitly call the `rollback` statement before/after the `throw` statement? Or will the `throw` itself rollback the update/insert. From my testing, the `throw` itself rolls back the update/insert. However, in Microsoft's own [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) on triggers, the `rollback` statement is included:

```
USE AdventureWorks2022;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID ('Purchasing.LowCredit','TR') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TRIGGER Purchasing.LowCredit;
GO
-- This trigger prevents a row from being inserted in the Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader table
-- when the credit rating of the specified vendor is set to 5 (below average).  
  
CREATE TRIGGER Purchasing.LowCredit ON Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader  
AFTER INSERT  
AS  
IF (ROWCOUNT_BIG() = 0)
RETURN;
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1  
           FROM inserted AS i   
           JOIN Purchasing.Vendor AS v   
           ON v.BusinessEntityID = i.VendorID  
           WHERE v.CreditRating = 5  
          )  
BEGIN  
RAISERROR ('A vendor''s credit rating is too low to accept new  
purchase orders.', 16, 1);  
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
RETURN   
END;
```

Is the inclusion of `rollback` really necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, absolutely not.**

Firstly, `THROW` always aborts the batch anyway, so the next statement is never executed, unless you have a `BEGIN CATCH`.

And `XACT_ABORT` is always `ON` in triggers, so a rollback happens anyway.

Even if you use `RAISERROR` which doesn't necessarily abort, if you `ROLLBACK` in a trigger then you get a spurious error:

```
Msg 3609 Level 16 State 1 Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

Some clients don't handle this properly, so you end up seeing only that error and not the actual error. So just use `THROW` by itself.

---

While Erland's "treatise" on error handling is excellent, it is widely misunderstood. It is about error **handling** ie dealing with an error, not throwing one.

In the *majority* of cases, you don't want to handle the error in SQL. You want the client to handle it, and for that you don't need any complex code, just `THROW` and `XACT_ABORT ON`.

Even `BEGIN CATCH` is poor: it doesn't catch all errors, and it can't handle multiple errors together as mentioned. If you need logging then use XEvents not some roll-your-own logger.

---

`;` is a statement terminator, not a beginning-ator. Terminate *all* your statements, or be terminated.

Comment: To keep the code DRY, I have put my validation checks in a stored proc, which is called by the trigger. The stored proc calls ;throw if a validation error is present. Does the stored proc change your answer? For example, do I need to set XACT_ABORT ON because I am now inside a stored proc?

Comment: Not if it's only ever called by triggers, because `XACT_ABORT ON` will feed through. if it is called from elsewhere then it might be best to add it as a precaution.